# How to check one of my object value is empty or not

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

I need to check my java object value is empty or not. And I need to check this one by one.
I crate my code to do this task...But I can't check values one by one. If all of my object value is empty, my code is working...But it can't check values one by one.

const coverDesc = action.data.coverDescriptionLocalization;

[image]

Methord 01- :-

```
 if (Object.values(coverDesc ).every((x) => x === null || x === '')) {
        console.log('Empty');
    } else {
        console.log('Not empty');
    }
```

Methord 02- :-

```
for (const key in coverDesc) {
    if (coverDesc.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        if (Object.values(coverDesc[key]).every((x) => x === null || x === '')) {
           console.log('Empty');
        } else {
            console.log('Not empty');
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to check whether there's a truthy value, you can do:

```
Object.keys(coverDesc).every((k) => coverDesc[k] === false)
```

If you need to check specifically for an empty string over null, I would think checking against "" is the best, using the === operator

```
Object.keys(coverDesc).every((k) => coverDesc[k] === false)
```